# Returning Twitter Users with keywords in Description in R

Tags: r, twitter

Is there a way to search twitter users which have a certain keyword in their 'description' field?  Right now my best thought is to write a loop to which will sequentially run through every user id, search the 'description' field and then only save the users which have that keyword.

Looping through every Twitter ID out there seems excessive!  Is there a better way or method?

Sub-question are their packages beyond twitteR and streamR for Twitter analysis in R?

P.S. as this is an entirely conceptual question, it was judged that no reproducible code was necessary... some can be provided if the question is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention this is an entirely conceptual question:

- twitter API offers search by users' profile description keywords by using the 'q' parameter: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search

You can even OAuth in the link above if you have the credentials and 'curl' test your query. If you simply don't want to build the query, just for the sake of checking feasibility I found this site where you can search by keywords in users' profile: https://moz.com/followerwonk/bio/ (I'm guessing they use Twitter's official API).

As for the R subquestion, I'm afraid I only know the ones you mentioned :-S

Comment: Doesn't this require that you also specify a user account as well?

Comment: Nope, actually not. I've just performed a quick test now through the Twitter OAuth Tool and randomly searched by query `q=chess%20yoga%consultant` and it returned me a profile of a guy containing this description ""Consultant and life long learner: sciences & technology, philosophy, chess, tennis and yoga"" and I didn't specify any user account.
Done this from terminal `curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json' --data 'amp%3Bcount=3&amp%3Bpage=1&q=chess+yoga%25consultant'` (plus my oauth credentials)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.  I clearly have more to learn about the Twitter API, which I can do on my own.  Thanks again!